# Rails console fails to start with error from I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

When I try to start console I get

```
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:158:in `load_file': can not load translations from /var/www/railsapp/config/locales/ru.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:71:in `lookup'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:26:in `translate'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:156:in `block in translate'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `catch'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:102:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /var/www/railsapp/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My app works fine, only console doesn't start.
May be this problem is related to upgrade from the second rails version. But for a year it has been worked fine.

My ru.yml:

```
ru:
 activerecord:
  attributes:
   user:
    password: "Пароль"
    login: "Имя пользователя"
    password_confirmation: "Повтор пороля"
  models:
   user: "пользователь"
```

It was a fantom error. After delete comments from ru.yml everything worked fine.

Comment: Is the yml file formatted correctly? I'm not sure if it matters, but my yml files that are used in rails 3 have 2 space indentation, it looks like yours has one space indentation.

Comment: I was using tabs and changing to 2 space indentation worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your `ru.yml` doesn't seems right, you probably need a double space indentation, rails doesn't see your translations as a hash, try change your yml to use two spaces.