# Error I18n::InvalidLocaleData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I want use I18n and I already follow on how to do that from `railscast` but the thing gone wild and I don't know where the mistake, had tried check the format, tried several ways but still can't be done.

my **`en.yml`**

```
en:
  category:
    index:
      title: "Listing Categories"
      name: "Name"
      is_active: "Is Active"
```

my **`view`**

```
<%= t 'category.index.title' %>
```

But return `I18n::InvalidLocaleData in Categories#index` and `can not load translations from /home/lenovo/cost_control/config/locales/en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not`

I had try on my **`en.yml`** just:

```
en:
  title: "Listing Categories"
```

and can work perfectly, but when I adding more line, just return me those error. I'm sorry I  just not so advanced yet in rails, thank you for the help you guys :D really.

Comment: Done checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286099/rails-console-fails-to-start-with-error-from-i18n)

Comment: And also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123406/gem-spree-i18n-throws-error-on-server-startup-can-not-load-translations)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems your YAML is broken. Didn't you use tabs instead of spaces?

You can use [YAMLlint](http://yamllint.com/) to check YAML for validity.

Comment: Yes sir, thanks. I just found it that must use tab instead of spaces. I think I should do like when I do on coffescript with tab. Now its work, thank you sir :D

Comment: FYI: You will also encounter this error if you have a colon (`:`) in a line of text that isn't quote-wrapped

Comment: does this have an autofix I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The validator Ilya recommends seemed pretty basic and not so great

Found this one which is better https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator