# I18n::InvalidLocaleData - can not load translations from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, erb

I using the i18n for internationalization.
but, occur the problem as blow.

config/locales/view/en.yml: expects it to return a hash, but does not

Although, I write yml with correct intent (2 space, no tap),
error is occur.
How could I resolve the problem ?

en.yml

```
en:
  moderna:
    language:
      en: English
      jp: Japanese
      kr: Korean
    menu:
      company: Company
      home: Home
    submenu:
      company:
        history: History
        introduce: Introduce
        philosophy: Philosophy
        subsidiary: Subsidiary
        vision: Vision
```

erb

```
<%= link_to t("moderna.menu.home"), xx_path %>
<%= link_to t("moderna.submenu.company.introduce"), introduce_path %>
<%= link_to t("moderna.submenu.company.history"), history_path %>
<%= link_to t("moderna.submenu.company.philosophy"), philosophy_path %>
<%= link_to t("moderna.submenu.company.subsidiary"), subsidiary_path %>
<%= link_to t("moderna.submenu.company.vision"), vision_path %>
```

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331873/error-i18ninvalidlocaledata  
maybe there is a tab in your yml file that you did not notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause. When you use i18n in project

1. should be generate file of internalization with different name.

   config/locales/default/en.yml
   config/locales/default/kr.yml
   config/locales/model/en.yml
   config/locales/model/kr.yml
   engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/default/en.yml
   engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/default/kr.yml
   engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/modle/en.yml
   engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/model/kr.yml

=> maybe occur error.[can not load translations from ~~~~~]
   so, I changed the file name as blow

```
config/locales/default/default_en.yml  
config/locales/default/default_kr.yml  
config/locales/model/model_en.yml  
config/locales/model/model_kr.yml  
engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/default/default_en.yml   
engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/default/default_kr.yml  
engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/modle/model_en.yml   
engines/hoge_engines/config/locales/model/model_kr.yml
```

2. Don't make empty file for internalization (yml).
   I made the empty yml file for use after. It also cause that raise error.

Comment: The second point (empty yml file) caused this exception for me.